# Linux ioctl for tty gives EPERM

Tags: c, linux, tty, ioctl

I try to implement a [getty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_(Unix)) program (the program, which acquires a specific tty, sets it to stdin, stdout and stderr and executes the login process normally; The typical implementation is `agetty`).

My problem is, it always gives me an EPERM error in the line with the `ioctl` call, which should change the controlling terminal.

The manpage about `ioctl_tty(2)` says:

> ```
>    TIOCSCTTY int arg
>           Make the given terminal the controlling terminal of the calling process.  The calling  process  must  be  a  session
>           leader and not have a controlling terminal already.  For this case, arg should be specified as zero.
>
>           If  this terminal is already the controlling terminal of a different session group, then the ioctl fails with EPERM,
>           unless the caller has the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability and arg equals 1, in which case the terminal is stolen,  and  all
>           processes that had it as controlling terminal lose it.
> ```

Now, if I just for test run it with superuser privileges (that means GID and UID = 0) theoretically the kernel should just skip the capabilities checks, according to the manpage `capabilities(7)`.

So what's wrong with the following code, when run as root:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stropts.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char path[50] = "/dev/";
    if (argc > 1) strcat (path, argv[1]);
            /* First argument is tty device name */
    else return 1;

    int fd = open (path, O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd == -1) return 1;

    ioctl (fd, TIOCSCTTY, 1); /* Here is the error */
}
```

Comment: Note: I tried it with 1 and 0 as argument; both fail.

Comment: Note: I suggest not assuming that all the terminals are in /dev if possible; it should take /dev/ttyWhatever as a parameter instead of just ttyWhatever.